# CodeIgniter site on Virtual Host on Mac without MAMP

Tags: macos, apache, codeigniter, mamp, vhosts

I’m keen to find out if there is a way of properly run virtual hosts on a Mac with apache without having to use things like MAMP or WAMP.
I have managed to get it to work for a small single page site and it worked seemlessly - However I am having no luck with trying to run a CodeIgniter frameworked site that way.

I would love to hear from anyone who has managed to carry this out successfully. Please let me know!

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice would be [Laravel Valet](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/valet), which is intended for Laravel, but works well with other frameworks. Support for CodeIgniter is not built-in, but you can always write your own custom driver, or use someone's driver like [this](https://github.com/rcubitto/laravel-valet-codeigniter/blob/master/CodeIgniterValetDriver.php) written by Github user @rcubitto

Comment: Oh thanks I did think of that but wasn’t too sure of how to implement it.

Comment: Hi Hai, I've just given [this](https://github.com/rcubitto/laravel-valet-codeigniter) a go as I already have Laravel Valet installed on my machine. However, for some reason I am still getting a "403 Forbidden You don't have permission to access / on this server".

Comment: Can you try running: sudo killall httpd, then: valet start, as suggested in [this thread](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/laravel-valet-403-forbidden-error)?

Comment: Yeah I did try that but no improvement.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on the situation? i.e. what url did you get the 403, do you have other httpd running, or did you run valet park? It's hard to guess what's wrong with such little information

Comment: Sure. I'm calling the url like this [the name of the project here].dev from the browser. Valet is parked in the projects folder where all my projects are including this particular one.

Comment: I just had time to fire up my Mac and try running the default CodeIgniter 3 downloaded from the official site. Just copy the folder to ~/Sites and it runs so smoothly out of the box, either with or without the custom driver. Maybe there's something wrong with your current environment. Also, you may be running an old version of valet, judging from the .dev domain name you're using. In the new valet, the default domain name is .test. Maybe reinstalling valet for a clean environment?

Comment: For a new CodeIgniter project, Laravel Valet seems to work fine thanks. Just tested it and it does the job. It's just that I am trying to run a legacy code igniter site the same way.